# Host strongloop/loopback on centos 7 server

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I installed loopback on my local machine, now uploaded to centos 7 server.

i tried to install PM by using "sudo sl-pm-install --systemd command", but it return me "sudo: sl-pm-install: command not found".

Can someone advise me how to install loopback on centos 7, and what i need to do to host it on production server.

And how to link my domain to run this loopback, which mean i access www.myweb.com, will return explorer page or loopback front page.

Comment: On CentOS `/use/local/bin` is not part of the default $PATH when running `sudo`. Similarly, you cannot use `nvm` with `sudo` without expanding the $PATH and even then it is not recommended for use with `sl-pm-install`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install the process manager on the CentOS system first: `sudo npm install -g strong-pm`

And of course, you need to have Node.js installed on the machine first.

Comment: yes, i did. but still not working. I installed nodejs, npm, and also strong-pm.
but still not working. Am i miss up some step? Can you brief me step by step?

Comment: That is the step-by-step... there's nothing else to it. If you don't have the command installed then my guess is that the install command in my answer above failed for some reason.

Comment: I uploaded loopback to server, in local normally we need run "node ." to start running loopback, but server how we set it run all the time, and after we run "node ." system will return me http://0.0.0.0:3000 but it not my ip address, how im going to change it?

Comment: That's a server administration question. Usually you only need to run the server on localhost (also known as 0.0.0.0 or 127.0.0.1) and open the correct port (3000 in this case). Your server should direct new requests to your machine (external IP address) to the localhost.